# Access the json object in react by using typescript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, api

I have never used typescript before but in this project I need to use that. I have my api which is sending me data as shown below. Api can not be changed because it is the client's api and he is not allowing me to change that. The problem is when i access the actuals.2020-01-01 it gives me parsing error. How can I access this json object by using typescript. I need to make a login in the function that it matches all the actuals with the year and date comming in the function and return the value of the actual which matches otherwise it will return "None". I have no idea how can I do that thing. I need to deliver that to the client in 2 hours.

```
//Backend
actuals: {
  "2020-01-01": {
    value: 1,
  },
  "2020-02-01": {
    value: 2,
  },
},

//Frontend
//Table
<tbody>
                                {dataSeries.map(
                                    (
                                        data: {
                                            name: string;
                                            actuals: JSON;
                                        },
                                        index: number
                                    ) => (
                                        <tr key={index}>
                                            {console.log(data)}
                                            <td>{data.name}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                {matchYearAndMonth(
                                                    monthBackward(0)
                                                        .currentyear,
                                                    monthBackward(0).month,
                                                    data.actuals
                                                )}
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {matchYearAndMonth(
                                                    monthBackward(1)
                                                        .currentyear,
                                                    monthBackward(1).month,
                                                    data.actuals
                                                )}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )
                                )}
</tbody>

//MatchYearAndMonth function

    const matchYearAndMonth = (year: number, month: number, actuals: JSON) => {
        console.log(actuals.2020-01-01);
        return year;
    };
```

Comment: try accessing using `actuals["2020-01-01"]`
Also, maybe change actuals type to something like `actuals: {[key: string]: object}`

Comment: tried that already. Still parsing error

Comment: What is the error exactly? Can you attach the error in the question?

Comment: If I try to access like actuals.2020-01-01 then I get "Parsing error: ',' expected" but if I access actuals["2020-01-01"] the I do not get error but get undefined in the console.

Comment: try console.log(actuals, actuals["2020-01-01"]) and see if the actuals is actually being passed to function.

Comment: yes actuals is passed in the function I am getting the values in console

Comment: You mentioned undefined, is it for all console logs? undefined means that the key doesn't exists. I just did this, check the types and see 
http://shorturl.at/pBC17

Comment: undefined is for actuals["2020-01-01"]. For other I am getting the parse error. Like if I want to access json objects by using a dot e.g. actuals.anything I am getting parse error which I mentioned above.

Comment: You cannot get value using dot in this as case as it contains dashes. What I meant when you got undefined, was it for all iterations? And does the key "2020-01-01" exists in your actuals. Also, see the link and try using the types there and the logs when you run the code.

Comment: okay..Got your point. I am getting undefined for the value which is not preset. For other I am getting {value:1}. How can I access that value now? and how can I match that 2020-01 with the coming year and month?

Comment: You can get the keys from an object using `Object.keys(actuals)`
This returns an array with values ["2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", ...]
Then you can loop through and convert to date using `Object.keys(actuals).forEach(v => { const d = new Date(v); })`

Comment: About coming year and month, are you talking about the current year (2020) and current month (September)?
Get the value using the current year and month?
`const d = new Date(); const value = actuals[d.getFullYear()+"-"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"-01"]`

Comment: Got it. And what about accessing the value of that actual?

Comment: By value I mean the 1 or 2. Now i am getting the value as {value:1}. I need that 1.

Comment: I've updated the code in the link, you can have a look at the ans comment as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type ActualsType = {[key: string]: {[key: string]: any, value: 1,}};
type DataSeriesType = {actuals: ActualsType, name: string};

function dateToStr(d=new Date()) {
  const y = d.getFullYear(),
        m = (d.getMonth()+1+"").padStart(2, "0"),
        day = (d.getDate()+"").padStart(2, "0");

  return `${y}-${m}-${day}`;
}

const today = new Date();
today.setDate(1);

const dataSeries: Array<DataSeriesType> = [
  {name: "Test 1", actuals: {
    "2020-01-01": {
      value: 1,
    },
    "2020-02-01": {
      value: 2,
    },
    "2020-09-01": {
      value: 9,
    },
  }},
  {name: "Test 2", actuals: {
    "2019-09-01": {
      value: 1.2,
    },
    "2019-10-01": {
      value: 2.2,
    },
  }},
];

const matchYearAndMonth = (year: number, month: number, actuals: ActualsType) => {
  const value = actuals[dateToStr(today)] ? actuals[dateToStr(today)]?.value : undefined;
  console.log(value);
  return {year, month, value};
};

dataSeries.map((v, i) => {
  const parsed = matchYearAndMonth(2020, i, v.actuals);
  // console.log(parsed);
})
```

Comment: I can't access the value by dot. actuals["2020-01-01"].value is not working.

Comment: You could use `actuals["2020-01-01"]["value"]` but I think it's undefined, that's why.
So you could check like in the `matchYearAndMonth` function `const value = ....`

Comment: Not working it is giving me error Property 'value' does not exist on type 'object'

Comment: Check at the top of the answer I had updated the types